# How to dynamically edit and save listitem text?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

Hello friends in this code i'm trying to edit the text of listitem and save the latest text in list item even after the app is closed over here we can successfully retrieve the text in a dialogue box with edit text option which is already in listitem just need to change the the pre-defined to any text
Help with this small thing 
Thanks in advance

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.vks_module;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
        final ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planetList);

        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) {
                String message = planetList.get(pos);
                final int positions = mainListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Change the name");

                final TextView plan_names = (TextView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.name);
                Button set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Set);
                plan_names.setText(message);
                set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String name = plan_names.getText().toString();

                        int pos = positions;
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && name.length() > 0) {
                            // remove
                            listAdapter.remove(planetList.get(pos));
                            // insert the updated one
                            listAdapter.insert(name, mainListView.getSelectedItemPosition());

                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Are you serious", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }

                    }

                });

                dialog.show();

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

**activitymain.xml**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vks_module.MainActivity" >
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/lv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>


**customedailog.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Set"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="SET" />

</RelativeLayout>


**LOGCAT**

03-28 00:17:38.767: D/AndroidRuntime(26713): Shutting down VM
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713): Process: com.example.vks_module, PID: 26713
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at com.example.vks_module.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-28 00:17:38.774: E/AndroidRuntime(26713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation for the method [getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()), it returns `INALID_ROW_ID` (whose value is -1) if nothing is selected. I think when you select an item in the `ListView` you're launching a `Dialog` which gains the focus and the item in the `ListView` becomes unselected which is why `mainListView.getSelectedItemPosition()` in your code is returning -1 always. Instead use the argument `pos` from the method `onItemClick()` as shown below.

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                                    long id) {
                String message = planetList.get(pos);
                final int positions = pos; //change here
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Change the name");

                final TextView plan_names = (TextView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.name);
                Button set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Set);
                plan_names.setText(message);
                set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String name = plan_names.getText().toString();
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && name.length() > 0) {
                            // remove
                            listAdapter.remove(planetList.get(positions)); //change here
                            // insert the updated one
                            listAdapter.insert(name, positions); //change here

                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Are you serious", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss(); //add this to dismiss dialogue after entering the string

                    }

                });

                dialog.show();

            }

        });
```

If you want to save the changes and get new values even after the app is restarted, you should save the new values in the database and use them to populate your array/arraylist in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: thanks bro it working good but as per the question can you help me need to save the edited list item even after the app as been completely closed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
final int positions = mainListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

So,
When you click on a ListView item it doesn't change his state to 'selected', so, when the event takes place and you do:

```
mainListView.getSelectedItem()
```

the method doesn't have anything to return. What you have to do is to use the position and obtain the underlaying object.

You already have the same in the variable pos, but you override it at

```
int pos = positions;
```

Check that and you are good to go!